# How can I use the IF statement to delimit cells in Excel, instead of Text to Columns or TEXTSPLIT?

Tags: excel, if-statement, delimiter

I'm trying to split cells with multiple forward slashes in between words. Some have 5, some have 7, some have 8.

Text to Columns doesn't work correctly, and my subscription doesn't have TEXTSPLIT.

I've tried using the above method but to no avail. Can I use an IF instead?

Comment: FIND() can be used to find the position of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd or Nth \. Then left(), mid() and right can be used. Usually needs iferror() as well, but since you don't show what you are working with then I cannot guess or provide an example, however there are already examples of find() on here.

Comment: Have you got acces to FILTERXML? Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194)

Comment: Think about left(A1,find("\",A1,1)-1) to get the first string.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.